# TASK folder under log directory is getting huge

Tags: logback, nexus3

We are using Nexus 3.41.1 and we observed that tasks folder under log directory is getting huge we already did log rotation in logback xml but not sure how to get this for tasks folder,

can you please guide,

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/tasks

task logs are removed after 30 days. Maybe look at your tasks and see what's logging so much?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).